# How do I show a checkboxes form element that is selected by default?

Tags: 7, forms

How do I show a *checkboxes* form element that is selected by default?

I tried setting `#default_value` as in the following code, but it doesn't work.

```php
$form['ios'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => $options,
  '#default_value' => 'checked',
);
```

Is `#default_value` the wrong attribute?

Comment: Have you tried this? `$form['ios'] = array('#type' => 'checkboxes', '#options' => $options, '#default_value' => array($value));` `$value` should be the option you want selected by default.

Comment: If you have a single field, you can use the following code. `$form['name']['terms_condition'] = array( '#type' =>'checkbox', '#title'=>t('Terms and conditions'), '#required'=>TRUE, '#default_value' =>TRUE);`

Comment: What happens here when the form is submitted with the checkbox unchecked but required set to `true`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`#default_value` for *checkboxes* form elements should be set as in the following code.

```php
$options = array();
$options["1"] = "One";
$options["2"] = "Two";
$options["3"] = "Three";
$options["4"] = "Four";

$form['ios'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => $options,
  '#default_value' => array("1", "2", "3")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give "#default_value" all $options keys

In your case:

```
$form['ios']['#default_value'] =  array_keys($form['ios']['#options']);
```

Comment: It depends on what _selected_ means for the OP, but to me it means at least one checkbox is selected. Since the OP already accepted an answer, I take he didn't mean that all the checkboxes needed to be selected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to checked all checkboxes values as default, you can use *checked* property in *#attribute*.

In your case:

```
$options = array();
$options["1"] = "One";
$options["2"] = "Two";
$options["3"] = "Three";
$options["4"] = "Four";

$form['ios'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => $options,
  '#attributes' => array('checked' => 'checked'),
);
```

This work for me.